# How did Sirius Black find 4, Privet Drive in PoA?

Tags: harry-potter

When Dumbledore first left Harry in the care of Petunia and Vernon, he invoked powerful protection charms to prevent the Death Eaters from finding Harry's location. At this point, it is assumed that Sirius Black is a Death Eaters. If that is the case, how was Sirius able to find Harry's house when it was supposed to have been protected? As Lily's friend, Sirius might have known the address, but the protection should've been stronger if it was known that Harry's location would be discovered - right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recall Dumbledore telling Harry that as long as he was with his kin, he was protected by love - until he would come of age at 17. I do not remember anywhere in canon that said Number 4, Privet Drive was under Fidelius.

It also could not have been protected because Ron had found the house with Fred and George in the beginning of CoS. Harry didn't ever tell Ron or Hermione his home address; he usually referred to it as Privet Drive, as Ron refers to his home as The Burrow, which is not the actual address.

Comment: Correct, it wasn't. It was only protecting Harry from a direct attack by Voldemort while he could call the place home, at least at that place specifically.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not aware of any answer from canon (books or interviews) but Sirius was one of the Marauders. He'd have known Lily extremely well (being James best friend and Harry's Godfather) and would have likely known that Lily's sister got married and to whom.

Also, I don't recall that Dumbledore actually **hid** Harry's location - the house wasn't under Fidelius.

Comment: But that was common knowledge - so what prevented the Death Eaters and other people who wanted to see "The Boy Who Lived" from tracking him?

Comment: @mustard - They could track him but couldn't **harm** him due to Dumbledore's protection based on Lily's sacrifice magic. On a separate note; I don't think it was "common knowledge" that one Muggle married another Muggle among Wizards - especially DEs).

Comment: Don't forget that Sirius loaned Hagrid his motorcycle.  It would not be unreasonable to assume that Sirius asked Hagrid where he was going.

Comment: @DVK By common knowledge - I meant that the Death Eaters surely knew about Lily's ancestry and had the means to track her sister if necessary.

Comment: @TGnat Sirius definitely knew Petunia's house - maybe even through Lily... but at that point - if Dumbledore believed Sirius to be Voldemort's right hand - wouldn't the precautions taken to hide Harry from the Death Eaters work against Sirius too?

Comment: I doubt that Dumbledore's protections were somehow designed for "Death Eaters" only as that is a designation.  The only magical aspect was the Death Mark.  My guess is Dumbledore's protection was against those who wished to do harm to Harry.  Sirius wasn't intending any harm to Harry so the protections wouldn't affect him.

Comment: As Dragona13 points out, how did Ron/Fred/George know where to find the Privot Drive house?

Comment: The were a lot of wizards who were very interested in the whereabouts of Harry Potter - everybody wanted to see "The boy who lived". If the protections were only against those who wished to harm Harry - why was the rest of the wizarding community unable to find him? And I think - since Ron was attempting to write letters to Harry and did not get a reply - he atleast knew the address to find Harry.

Comment: @Treborcram Dark Mark. But I am pretty sure the protection only applied directly against Voldemort since it was an extension of Lily's sacrifice that he used as part of the enchantment. The same sacrifice that meant he couldn't touch Harry and which he worked around on that in his rebirth by using Harry's blood.

Comment: @mustard It was only against Voldemort, in fact, and the protection was he couldn't be **harmed by** Voldemort there while he still could call it home. Nothing to do with hiding the place at all. Otherwise how would they have known to be there for the ambush in DH if they didn't know where it was? Only when Harry agrees that he will call it home no more (or when he turns 17) is the enchantment lifted but the Death Eaters knew in advance because Severus had to reveal the real departure date. Thus they were there to ambush. And at that point Voldemort could harm him even there.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that Sirius was not really at Privet Drive 4. Harrys first encounter with him was after he left and was standing on the street. So even if the house was protected, it might just be that he waited until Harry left the house.

Comment: yes - I forgot that Harry had left the house. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't it be as simple as, the charm was to protect him from Death Eaters, but as he wasn't one, the charm didn't affect Sirius?

Comment: It was Voldemort only and it wasn't said to be anything but that he couldn't harm Harry there rather than hiding the place.